# how to split the values of column in datatable of dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my dataset I have many rows,

```
In first row last column has the value is "12356.56@Firefox 1@23423"
In Second row same column has the value is "12356.56@Chrome2.0@23423"
In Third row same column has the value is "3423@Firefox 14.0@sdfsd"
```

here instead of displaying same value like above..

```
I need to display just "Firefox" if that column has Firefox in UI

I need to display just "Chrome" if that column has Chromein UI
```

how can i do it...

Answer (score 1):

Use this helper function

```
public static string GetBrowser(string str)
{
    str = str.ToUpper();
    if(str.Contains("CHROME"))
    {
        return "Chrome";
    } 
    else if(str.Contains("FIREFOX")) 
    {
        return "Firefox";
    }
    return "Unknown";
}
```

Then when you bind the dataset to the UI use it to display the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of things you want to check for, you can use `.Contains` to check:

```
var myValue = myDS[rowIndex][lastColumn].ToString();
if (myValue.Contains("Firefox"))
    return "Firefox";
else if (myValue.Contains("Chrome"))
    return "Chrome";
else
    return "Unknown";
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/pMVeD

---

From the examples you've given, it appears the following logic *may* work, but it should be tested against a wider variety of sample values:

```
var myValue = myDS[rowIndex][lastColumn].ToString();
var parts = myValue.Split('@');
var browser = parts[1].Split(' ','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
return browser[0];
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/NrY1e

Answer (score 1):

Here is code. This might help.

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add("table0");
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("browser");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc);
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("12356.56@Firefox1@23423");
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string str = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            if((str.ToLower().CompareTo("firefox"))!=0)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] = "firefox";
            }
        }
        _gridView.DataSource = ds;
        _gridView.DataBind();
```